# What's the reason Javascript primitive types (string, number ...) are immutable and referenced types (objects, array) are mutable

Tags: javascript, memory, primitive-types

I wonder if the reason is that Primitive types are stored in STACK memory, which it's a limited size memory, in the opposite HEAP memory is used for dynamic variables.

I want to know the reason why primitive variables cannot be changed... (security, perform, memory) ...

Thank you all

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's because Java works that way too (JavaScript was inspired by Java). I'd even go so far and say that this common among languages, but I don't have proof. It's unlikely you will get an authoritative answer her, maybe reach out to Brendan (e.g. Twitter).

Comment: "*Primitive types are stored in STACK memory*" - no, what makes you think that? Primitive values can be stored on the heap as well. And no, this has nothing to do with mutability.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you mean.

```js
var a = '';
console.log(typeof a); // string
a = 5;
console.log(typeof a); // number
```

Comment: Immutatation doesn't mean reassignment. I know var change be reassigned